# sweetalert2 cancel timer/timeout

Tags: javascript, timer, modal-dialog, sweetalert2

I wanted to make a cancelable self-closing modal after 5 seconds with SweetAlert2 but I could't find a way to stop the timer, please help! Here's the js code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#view_more_trigger', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = document.getElementById('view_more');
    div.style.display = div.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    $(this).html( div.style.display == 'none' ? "View Moar" : "View Less");
});

var closeInSeconds=10,
    timerInterval;

var my_swal = swal({
    type:   'success',
    html:   '<div id="view_more" style="display: none;">'+
                $('#details').html() +
            '</div>'+
            '<a href="javascript:;" id="view_more_trigger" >View more</a>'+
            '<p id="show_timeout" style="display: none;"></p>',
    timer: closeInSeconds * 1000,

    onOpen: () => {

        $('#show_timeout').show();
        timerInterval = setInterval(function() {

            $(document).on('click', '#view_more_trigger', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();

                console.log('trying desperately to cancel the damn timer!');
                //swal.stop();                //  error, function !exists
                //my_swal.timeout.stop();     //  Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined
                //my_swal.timer.stop();       //  Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined


                // ..or to increase it
                if(closeInSeconds<1000) {
                    console.log('incrementing closeInSeconds by 1000');
                    closeInSeconds +=1000;
                }
                //swal.timer = closeInSeconds * 1000;

                swal.timer = closeInSeconds * 1000;
                my_swal.timer = closeInSeconds * 1000;

                clearInterval(timerInterval);
            });

            closeInSeconds--;
            if (closeInSeconds < 0) {
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
            }

            swal.getContent().querySelector('#show_timeout').textContent = (Math.round(swal.getTimerLeft()/1000)*1000)/1000 + 's';

        }, 1000);
    },
    onClose: () => {
        clearInterval(timerInterval)
    },

    showConfirmButton: false,
});
```

The only function to work with timer I found is Swal.getTimerLeft().

I created a pen in https://codepen.io/teoui/pen/MzdzWy to play with

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `setInterval`, did you perhaps mean to use `setTimer`?

Comment: the problem is the `timer` of `swal()` options, which I don't know how to stop(or increase) it. `timeout` of `setInterval()` is for determining how often the countdown in `p#show_timeout` is shown. Maybe should have named `timerInterval`, like in [https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) (see "A message with auto close timer")

Comment: You're assigning a new click handler to `document` each time that dialog is opened. That doesn't seem right. I'm trying to create a [mcve] based on your code, but I'm not sure about the HTML. As for `swal.stop();`, your alert is called `my_swal`.

Comment: Chris, I'm not good at js; :D I tried both by class name(`swal`) and by its instance(variable) `my_swal`. As for #mcve, see my pen in the updated post.

Comment: Fixed it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/njpL4dsz/ I basically removed the timer from the swal instance; I don't have to use the built-in one to close the alert after all.

Comment: That's great!! Many thanks Chris, it's magical! :)

Comment: As I'm new to this, I don't know how to upvote you. Maybe you should move your comment with the jsfiddle as an Answer? Could my question be marked as "[solved]"? I've credited you in [https://codepen.io/teoui/pen/xQNMvL](https://codepen.io/teoui/pen/xQNMvL) anyway, giving some more explanations in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of SweetAlert2, and a new version with `Swal.stopTimer()` support was just released.

Here's how you can use it:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Auto close alert!',
  html: 'I will close in 5 seconds. <a href id="stop-timer">Stop timer</a>',
  timer: 5000,
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('#stop-timer').addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      Swal.stopTimer()
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much!!  - so quick! I think your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMVYKz) demo works&looks better than SO's snippet